# Scalable parsing of images in nodejs

Tags: node.js, image-processing

I am setting a new service, in which i need to deal with image parsing. The code for image parsing is a simple js function which does some manipulation on each pixel and is some-what time consuming(say 10-15) seconds for large images. 
My initial thought was setting it up in nodejs since i know it and the parsing function is in javascript. But since its single threaded, i don't seem to get how make it scalable for handling 1000s of request at the same time. I understand how i/o is handled in node, and there are ways of making cpu intensive task async like the one suggested in this blog.
https://medium.com/@badewakayode/running-cpu-intensive-task-in-nodejs-db4f995db310

But is nodejs really helpful in cases like this. Or should I switch to some other options like go-lang, java, c++.

Comment: Something isn't quite adding up here.  1000s of requests at the same time for something that takes 10-15 seconds of a CPU to process each request is not something that gets solved by picking a different language.   If you want timely responses, then you will need a lot of CPUs to apply to the problem (horizontal scaling).  Or, if you just want to apply one system at the problem, then you'd probably create a work queue and a set of worker processes  (one per CPU core) and work on them N at a time in order.  Either of these can be done fine in node.js.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that you should scale this horizontally using AWS Lambda or some other serverless solution. You can set up a node.js function to be triggered when an image is uploaded to your S3 bucket and automatically process it. Lambda will also scale up instances to deal with heavy utilization

Here are a couple of articles along those lines:

https://read.acloud.guru/serverless-image-optimization-and-delivery-510b6c311fe5
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/